# How to run Http request twice without duplicates?

Tags: jmeter

I have this structure in my Test Plan:

```
Test Plan
- Thread Group
-- HttpRequest (SendMessage)
-- HttpRequest (GetNewMessages)
-- HttpRequest (SendMessage)  (duplicate)
-- HttpRequest (GetNewMessages) (duplicate)
-- HttpRequest (SendMessage) (duplicate)
-- HttpRequest (GetNewMessages) (duplicate)
```

If i change something on the server side in SendMessage or GetNewMessages i must change it in all HttpRequests.

How can i declare (HttpRequest) once and use it in another places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables/properties to hold the message, but it can be complicated so you can put each HTTP Request as a Test Fragment and add it with a [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) several times and therefore you will have no duplicates

[image]

Another option is saving each HTTP Request as a separate JMX and use [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) but I think it have an overhead.

Also you have a simple solution - you can put in a loop with loop count 3 your 2 HTTP requests to achieve same flow.

Answer (score 1):

You're violating [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), instead of copying and pasting requests consider [using Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) and store any test elements you will be re-using in your Test Plan as [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)